# Pulling a container on kubernetes/Google Cloud) is super slow - 8 minutes - f1-micro instance

Tags: performance, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, pull

Pulling a container on kubernetes/Google Cloud), from private registry on Docker Hub, is very very slow - 10 minutes using a 3 nodes cluster of f1-micro instances.

Which are the best practices to speed up the pull of containers on google cloud compute engine?

Comment: This isn't a question.

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: You could use https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/using-dockerhub-mirroring this should reduce the time considerbaly in my experience